# How to get last item for GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id transaction_id auto_recurring paid_amount package_customerid
37              0              1           0                  4
45             37              1           0                  4
51              0              1           0                  4
57             51              1           0                  4
62              0              1           0                  4
67             62              1           0                  4
```

There are 6 records of package_customer_id = 4. Now I want to get the last record of 4. in this case id = 67 is my desired record. I try this `SELECT * FROM transactions GROUP BY package_customer_id`. But I got first record of package_customer_id = 4. i.e: id = 4 is my fetched result. How can I get  id = 67 (my desired record) modifying this sql?

Comment: Be aware that when using "Group By" you aren't necessarily getting a record back. You will get a collection of fields that match the selection criteria. The fields in the selection (where your "*" is) need to either be represented in a where clause or be using aggregate functions like MAX https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html Newer version of MySQL  will give you an error if you try to do this.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE package_customer_id = 4 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

That would be my shot at it. Sorry but i haven't tested it, i leave it up to you:)

EDIT:

<s>Dont forget the quotes " ` " on columns name's:)</s>

Check you column name `package_customer_id` OR `package_customerid` ?

Comment: backticks only needed if the field is a "reserved word"

Comment: And apostrophes are only needed if possessive - so "column's name" or leave it out, as in "column names"

Comment: @Strawberry what about contractions?  I generally don't use them but... :P  Note: Keywords do not need backticks

Comment: @xQbert Likewise, I ain't never used one, so don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: This will never work as required

Comment: This query will give the exact result as required 
 SELECT temp.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE package_customer_id = 4 order by id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS temp GROUP BY temp.package_customer_id

Comment: @xQbert thanks for the edit:) i'm not really grammar friendly:D thats why i look there first when debugging :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `group by`.  Use `where`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions t
WHERE t.id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id)
              FROM transactions t2
              WHERE t2.package_customer_id = t.package_customer_id
             );
```

You can filter this for whichever package customer ids you like, in the outer query.

Comment: Doesn't handle package_CustomerID = 4

Answer (score 0):

You may try this .

```
SELECT temp.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE package_customer_id = 4 order by id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS temp GROUP BY temp.package_customer_id
```

Comment: Doesn't handle package_CustomerID = 4

Comment: @xQbert OH !! i skiped this point , anyways  i can add where condition inside the subquery

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM transactions GROUP BY package_customerid)
```

Comment: Doesn't handle package_CustomerID = 4

Answer (score -1):

try this query

if you need with GROUP BY clause: use this query

```
SELECT * FROM transactions where GROUP BY package_customerid ORDER BY package_customerid DESC LIMIT 1;
```

OR
if you DON'T need with GROUP BY clause: use this query

```
SELECT MAX(id),transaction_id,auto_recurring,paid_amount,package_customerid FROM transactions where package_customerid=4;
```

**Output:**

```
id transaction_id auto_recurring paid_amount package_customerid
67             62              1           0                  4
```

Comment: In the question , mentioned that use Group by clause

Comment: I never understood using aggregation w/o a group by when the field values were different. so what transaction_ID would be selected here?  why is it 62? and not 0 51 or 37?